# How to reset python logger in a callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

Hello here is my promblem : i work with a broker and a daemon which is listening it and each time a message (containing a file) comes in a callback function is triggered in my code like this :

```
def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body,args):
    (conn, thrds) = args
    delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work, args=(conn, ch, delivery_tag, body))
    t.start()
    thrds.append(t)

#callback=staticmethod(callback)
def do_work(self, conn, ch, delivery_tag, body):
    thread_id = threading.get_ident()
    logging.basicConfig(filename=self.dict_config["filelog"]+"exchange_hashed" +'_'+str(thread_id)+'_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')) + '.log',level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger('exchange_hashed'+str(thread_id))

    logger.info('Thread id: %s Delivery tag: %s', thread_id,delivery_tag)
    payload = body.decode("utf-8")
    payload = json.loads(payload)
    file_content = payload["values"]
    file_path = file_content["header"]["meta_data"]["file_name"]
    filename=file_path.split("/")[-1]
    logger.info(f"Data received for {filename}")
```

in the function `do_work()` i initialize my logger and name it with it's thread id but instead of creating a new log file for each thread, it keeps writing in the first which was created.

I've check logging doc and they say : Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.

so it's exactly what i am NOT doing

I don't understand what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve separate log files for each thread, I have manually create and configure a new logger for each thread in the `do_work` method. Here's an updated version of my code that should create separate log files for each thread:

```
import logging
import threading
from datetime import datetime

def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body, args):
    (conn, thrds) = args
    delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work, args=(conn, ch, delivery_tag, body))
    t.start()
    thrds.append(t)

def do_work(self, conn, ch, delivery_tag, body):
    thread_id = threading.get_ident()

    # Create a new logger for each thread
    logger = logging.getLogger('exchange_hashed.' + str(thread_id))
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # Create a new file handler for each thread
    filename = self.dict_config["filelog"] + "exchange_hashed_" + str(thread_id) + '_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')) + '.log'
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # Configure the log format
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # Add the file handler to the logger
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    logger.info('Thread id: %s Delivery tag: %s', thread_id, delivery_tag)
    payload = body.decode("utf-8")
    payload = json.loads(payload)
    file_content = payload["values"]
    file_path = file_content["header"]["meta_data"]["file_name"]
    filename = file_path.split("/")[-1]
    logger.info(f"Data received for {filename}")
```